# can't hit vue method from within axios response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't figure out what's wrong here, but my axios call works properly and my data response comes back as I expect with success.

The issue now is when I try to call another vue method within my response success from axios. If I comment out the method call then it's fine, but if I leave it the console just reads undefined and I don't get the console.log from within my testFunction so it seems like I'm not even hitting it.

What have I done wrong?

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  methods: {
   axiosFunc() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: test,
      data: {
        date:'2022-03-02',
      }

    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log('success');
      this.testFunction();

    }).catch(function (error) {
     
    });
   },
   testFunction() {
     console.log('in new function');
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="axiosFunc()">Console log</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63726131/8172857

Comment: Like @BoussadjraBrahim say, you using `this` in another context of your Vue component. Try to replace `function (response) { this.testFunction() }` by `(response) => this.testFunction()` to avoid this issue.

Comment: @7-zete-7 I'm confused how to use the arrow notation for multiple calls though (in this case I have a console.log as well as the function call, but say I also wanted to call another function simultaneously).

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm still confused how the arrow notation works while I'm still using axios({ format and have multiple things going on within my response function (such as a console log and a function call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your

```js
...
.then(function (response) {
  console.log('success');
  this.testFunction();
})
...
```

by

```js
...
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.testFunction();
})
...
```

To avoid context override.

You can also use this code:

```js
...
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  this.testFunction();
}.bind(this))
...
```

Or

```js
...
const that = this;
...
.this(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
  that.testFunction();
})
...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank yoU!

Comment: Hi! I had a question, can I do something like `.then(this.response)` where `response` is defined in methods and can accept parameters? Also, on your last option, should that be `.then` instead of `.this`? Thank you!

Comment: @Riz-waan, in this case, when executing the `response` method, there will be a loss of context (`this`). To avoid this, it will be necessary either to wrap the call to the `response` method in an anonymous function (as in the answer), or use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to assign the context manually.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, the function seems to work without a problem for me. The only context I am using is setting states. Maybe you mean context of the axios will be lost?

Comment: @Riz-waan, I meen [function and class context (`this`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context).